# Unable insert element in nested array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am working on angular tree which is having a large nested array.

*nodes* :

```
public fonts: TreeModel = {
    value: 'Fonts',
    children: [
      {
        value: 'Serif  -  All my children and I are STATIC ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯',
        settings: {
          'static': true
        },
        children: [
          { value: 'Antiqua' },
          { value: 'DejaVu Serif' },
          { value: 'Garamond' },
          { value: 'Georgia' },
          { value: 'Times New Roman' },
          {
            value: 'Slab serif',
            children: [
              { value: 'Candida' },
              { value: 'Swift' },
              { value: 'Guardian Egyptian' }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        value: 'Sans-serif',
        children: [
          { value: 'Arial' },
          { value: 'Century Gothic' },
          { value: 'DejaVu Sans' },
          { value: 'Futura' },
          { value: 'Geneva' },
          { value: 'Liberation Sans' }
        ]
      }
    ]};
```

The Tree looks similar to one present in image :   [image]

Each time user clicks on Any node, an API request goes to bring Child of that node (JSON Array). then i need to append this response array into original tree array . 
The problem I'm facing is how do i insert child of nodes dynamically into original array against the parent node user clicked on.

Any better solution of current problem will also be  helpful for me. 
Currently i am using angular2-tree-component to implement the tree.

Comment: Objects are all passed by reference, just keep a reference to the clicked object and append your data on the server response.

Comment: If you have a reference to the node that was clicked on, why not append children to it directly? We may need to see your code to give you specific tips on how to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution.

I switched to ng2-tree to implement the tree.
It has all the in built methods for tree-nodes and also it is well documented.
[npm: ng2-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-tree)

For every node provide an id. When user clicks on any node call a method to add childs into it.

```
public addChildFFS(id: number | string, newNode: TreeModel) {

    newNode.id = ++this.lastFFSNodeId;
    const treeController = this.treeFFS.getControllerByNodeId(id);
    if (treeController) {
        treeController.addChild(newNode);
    } else {}
}
```